# How to marry NioServerSocketChannelFactory and WorkManager

Tags: netty, jca

I am looking to implement a JCA Resource adapter to accept socket connections from within J2EE container.

I need to somehow be able to use [WorkManager](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html) to manage threads in netty's [NioServerSocketChannelFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioServerSocketChannelFactory.html) 
Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! NioServerSocketChannelFactory takes two Executor(s), boss and worker, as parameters to  the constructor. so all I need to do is develop a facade to WorkManager to implement execute(Runnable) method that will use workManager.schedule(...) call.